# Selenium doesn't show table content after ::before

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the table of brazillian debentures with BS4 and Selenium (BS4 by itself scraped even less information than with Selenium) .

(http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/#/detalharOferta?ano=MjAyMQ%3D%3D&valor=MTU%3D&comunicado=MQ%3D%3D&situacao=MQ%3D%3D)

When I print the web page after BeautifulSoup, the table after `::before` doesn't show up, I've tried using `find_all('div', class_="col-lg-12")` where the table is supposed to begin  and I get an empty array.

Is there a way to make that content show up? I've already tried using an implicit wait and the information didn't load aswell.

Here is my code:

```
url = 'http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/#/detalharOferta?ano=MjAyMQ%3D%3D&valor=MTU%3D&comunicado=MQ%3D%3D&situacao=MQ%3D%3D'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-lg-12")
print(tags)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you don't want to use `Selenium`/`BeautifulSoup`, the table is available with sending a `POST` request to:

```
http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/consultarOfertaController/consultarValorMobiliario
```

while providing the correct `headers` (as the below example).

You can get the table, however, the table headers are loaded from:

```
http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/application/message/i18n.js
```

Here's an example of how to load the data:

```
import requests


headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "Origin": "http://web.cvm.gov.br",
    "Referer": "http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/",
}

data = '{"ano":"2021","valorMobiliarioId":"15","comunicado":"1","situacao":"1","situacaoEncerrada":false,"situacaoAndamento":true,"tipoComunicado":"INICIAL"}'

response = requests.post(
    "http://web.cvm.gov.br/app/esforcosrestritos/consultarOfertaController/consultarValorMobiliario",
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: That's actually great, however it would be a different assignment of what was given to me, since I'd have to use BS4/Selenium and later pandas to work with the data.
Thanks so much for that insight!

Comment: @JoaoVilar You can still use pandas: with `pd.json_normalize()`. i.e: `pd.json_normalize(response.json())`